# Read and Delete one or more message from azure service bus topic using logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-topics

Can we Read and Delete one or more message from azure service bus topic using logic app?
what does the Complete Message Action will do on a Logic App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Read**

You could read a message from the service bus. You could use one of the below connectors and triggers :

[Get messages from a queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#get-messages-from-a-queue-(peek-lock))
[Get messages from a topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#get-messages-from-a-topic-subscription-(peek-lock))

Or you could use one the following triggers which will get the message content to be read :

1. When a message is received in a queue (auto-complete)
2. When a message is received in a queue (peek-lock)
3. When a message is received in a topic subscription (auto-complete)
4. When a message is received in a  topic subscription (peek-lock)
5. When one or more messages arrive in a queue (auto-complete) When one
   or more messages arrive in a queue (peek-lock)
6. When one or more messages arrive in a topic (auto-complete)
7. When one or more messages arrive in a topic    (peek-lock)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#triggers

**Complete Message Action**  (Also - Delete)

The operation completes a message in a queue or topic depending on which conector you use.

What does **completes a message** mean ?
When the receive operation is initiated, the message is locked by the receiving client. The message in the queue/topic remains undeleted. In case the message is not **completed**, the message would be available to be consumed again for the receiving clients after the lock expires.

So in short **complete a  message** means that the message should be marked as processed and deleted from the queue or topic.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#get-messages-from-a-queue-(peek-lock)

**Update :**

You could do something like below :

[image]

**Explanation :**

The above logic app gets triggered on a http request with the messages count that needs to be read.

Subsequently mentioned count of messages is retrieved from the service bus - topic combination and completed eventually.

Comment: thanks for the response. Here I am looking to use Get messages from a topic Subscription Action in which I will be given with multiple messages as per the count That I provided. As I read all these messages, I would like to mark each message as complete. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @KarthikDheeraj - updated my answer to meet your requirement. note - you change the trigger for your convenience

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped :)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work